# Pandas DataFrame Median Function

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, axis, median

If I have a Pandas DataFrame and want to calculate the median value for each column, it seems that the argument axis=1 should give the median by columns (according to the documentation). But in practice, axis=0 gives the column medians. Here is a simple replicable example:

```
import pandas as pd

my_data = [[1.1, 2.2, 3.3], [1.2, 2.3, 3.4], [1.3, 2.4, 3.5]]
df = pd.DataFrame(my_data)
print(df.head())

print("\nTry to calculate median with axis=1\n")

print(df.median(axis=1))
```

It is showing the median by row. Changing it to axis=0 shows the median by column. Does this have to do with the way that the index is set for the DataFrame?

Comment: What exactly "other Python functions" do you have in mind saying that pandas `axis` semantics is inconsistent with them? Also, seems that all functions mentioned in this docs section, including `apply`, are consistent in `axis` semantics: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/computation.html#method-summary

Comment: The drop function for DataFrame comes to mind: to drop from columns, you specify axis=1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does what it is supposed to do, `axis = 1` means to apply the function each row. You can see from this other example

```
>>> print(df.sum(axis = 1))
0    6.6
1    6.9
2    7.2
dtype: float64
```

Or equivalently

```
>>> print(df.apply(sum, axis = 1))
0    6.6
1    6.9
2    7.2
dtype: float64
```

and you can see in the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)

```
axis : {0 or ‘index’, 1 or ‘columns’}, default 0

Axis along which the function is applied:

0 or ‘index’: apply function to each column.
1 or ‘columns’: apply function to each row.
```

So if you want to calculate the mean of each row column you should use `axis = 0`

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. It seems unfortunate that 'columns' is how you specify the function should apply to each row, but I see where it comes from.

Answer (score 0):

Some of pandas function axis=0 and axis=1 is not always consist So that I recommend

```
df.median(axis='columns')
0    2.2
1    2.3
2    2.4
dtype: float64
```